# QTabWidget как заблокировать одну вкладку

Tags: qt

У меня появилась проблема с QTabWidget у меня не получалось "заблокировать " одну вкладку ,а не все сразу .

```
 ui->tabWidget->setEnabled(1);
```

Так не работает .
Обращаясь на прямую к вкладке тоже:

```
   ui->tab_2->setEnabled(false);
```

И обращаясь через QTabWidget вызываю QWidget (я даже не знал что так можно делать )

```
   ui->tabWidget->widget(1)->setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ :

```
ui->tabWidget->setTabEnabled(1,false);
```

p.s. Знаю  вопрос выглядит глупым и наивным , но я на него пол дня потратил .